# Set karate mock server port

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

Is there a a way to set a port to my desired one when I am starting a mock serve with `karate.start`
so instead of getting the port like this, which will start server in some port and return it:

```
def startMockServer = () => karate.start('path.feature').port
```

Have a possibility similar to this:

```
def startMockServer = () => karate.start('path.feature', '8080')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
* karate.start({ mock: 'mock.feature', port: 8080 })
```

This is mentioned in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#within-a-karate-test